# Checking for words in a string in Python

Tags: python

I have followed some examples on here for doing exactly what I am asking but I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Basically, I want to find out if a given string contains any words from a list of words.

```
st = "hello this is a string"
ar = ['lo', 'str']

if any(e in st for e in ar):
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```

However I am getting True for this input. And similarly, when trying with some matching words I am getting False. Every source I have checked says to use the any in the way shown above to do what i desire. I just can't seem to get the hang of it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to split the string into words for the `any` function to pick up the items in ar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into words and use list comprehension to check if there is at least one match

```
words=st.split(' ')
any([a==word for word in words for a in ar])
# False
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am extremely new to python so I really appreciate the kind and accurate response!